ws error: Unexpected server response: 503
I’ve written a raydium new lp monitor code, it runs well, but it got ws error: Unexpected server response: 503 todays morning. Then, I tried to restart it, it haven't printed the ws error: Unexpected server response: 503 anymore, but  the program didn't show any lp infomation anymore. I've tried adding some console logs under
connection.onLogs(
    programAddress,
    ({ logs, err, signature }) => {

but it goes nothing, it means the onLogs callback haven't be call. So I reckon it has two reason lead to the error, 1. the connection problem, 2. The return from RPC got some format error. anyone can help me?
below is my code
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import {
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  PartiallyDecodedInstruction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3 } from "@raydium-io/raydium-sdk";
import { logger } from "./logger";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ path: "../.env" });
import { PgService } from "./database";
import { Dao } from "./dao";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

const specialAddresses = [
  "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
  "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
  "Es9vMFrzaCERmJfrF4H2FYD4KCoNkY11McCe8BenwNYB",
];


const configPath = process.argv[2];
const config = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, configPath), "utf8")
);

const pgConfig = config.pg;
const g_pg_service = new PgService(pgConfig);
const g_pool = g_pg_service.getPool();
const g_dao = new Dao();
// const HTTP_URL = process.env.HTTP_URL || "";
// const WSS_URL = process.env.WSS_URL || "";

const OPENBOOK_PROGRAM_ID = "srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX";
const raydiumAuthority = "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1";

const RAYDIUM_POOL_V4_PROGRAM_ID =
  "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8";
const RAYDIUM = new PublicKey(RAYDIUM_POOL_V4_PROGRAM_ID);
const INSTRUCTION_NAME = "initialize2";

const SOL_TOKEN = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112";
const SOL_DECIMALS = 9;

const conn = new Connection(config.http_url);
let wssConn: Connection;

const metaplex = new Metaplex(conn);

const RECONNECT_INTERVAL = 5000; 

async function startConnection(
  connection: Connection,
  programAddress: PublicKey,
  searchInstruction: string
): Promise<void> {
  logger.info("Monitoring logs for program: ", programAddress.toString());

  connection.onLogs(
    programAddress,
    ({ logs, err, signature }) => {
      if (err) return;

      if (logs && logs.some((log) => log.includes(searchInstruction))) {
        const message =
          `\n--------------------\n` +
          `Signature for initialize2: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${signature}\n` +
          `https://solscan.io/tx/${signature}`;

        logger.info(message);

        fetchRaydiumMints(signature, wssConn);
      }
    },
    "finalized"
  );
}

function findLogEntry(
  needle: string,
  logEntries: Array<string>
): string | null {
  for (let i = 0; i < logEntries.length; ++i) {
    if (logEntries[i].includes(needle)) {
      return logEntries[i];
    }
  }

  return null;
}

function extractLPInitializationLogEntryInfoFromLogEntry(lpLogEntry: string): {
  nonce: number;
  open_time: number;
  init_pc_amount: number;
  init_coin_amount: number;
} {
  const lpInitializationLogEntryInfoStart = lpLogEntry.indexOf("{");

  return JSON.parse(
    fixRelaxedJsonInLpLogEntry(
      lpLogEntry.substring(lpInitializationLogEntryInfoStart)
    )
  );
}

function fixRelaxedJsonInLpLogEntry(relaxedJson: string): string {
  return relaxedJson.replace(
    /([{,])\s*([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\s*:/g,
    '$1"$2":'
  );
}

async function fetchMarketInfo(conn: Connection, marketId: PublicKey) {
  const marketAccountInfo = await conn.getAccountInfo(marketId);
  if (!marketAccountInfo) {
    throw new Error(
      "Failed to fetch market info for market id " + marketId.toBase58()
    );
  }

  return MARKET_STATE_LAYOUT_V3.decode(marketAccountInfo.data);
}

async function fetchRaydiumMints(txId: string, connection: Connection) {
  try {
    const tx = await connection.getParsedTransaction(txId, {
      maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
      commitment: "confirmed",
    });

    //@ts-ignore
    const accounts = (
      tx?.transaction.message.instructions.find(
        (ix): ix is PartiallyDecodedInstruction =>
          "accounts" in ix &&
          ix.programId.toBase58() === RAYDIUM_POOL_V4_PROGRAM_ID
      ) as PartiallyDecodedInstruction
    ).accounts as PublicKey[];

    if (!accounts) {
      logger.warn("No accounts found in the transaction");
      return;
    }

    const poolIndex = 4;
    const openOrdersIndex = 6;
    const lpMintIndex = 7;
    const tokenAIndex = 8;
    const tokenBIndex = 9;
    const baseVaultIndex = 10;
    const quoteVaultIndex = 11;
    const marketIdIndex = 16;
    const walletSignerIndex = 17;

    const poolAccount = accounts[poolIndex];
    const tokenA = accounts[tokenAIndex];
    const tokenB = accounts[tokenBIndex];
    const marketIdAccount = accounts[marketIdIndex];

    const poolAddr = poolAccount.toString();
    let mintAddr = tokenA.toString();
    let mintAddrB = tokenB.toBase58();
    if (
      specialAddresses.includes(mintAddr) &&
      !specialAddresses.includes(mintAddrB)
    ) {
      [mintAddr, mintAddrB] = [mintAddrB, mintAddr];
      logger.info(`swap mintAddr and mintAddrB: ${mintAddr}, ${mintAddrB}`);
    }
    const mintAddressPk = new PublicKey(mintAddr);

    const nft = await metaplex
      .nfts()
      .findByMint({ mintAddress: mintAddressPk });

    let name = nft.name;
    let symbol = nft.symbol;
    let uri = nft.uri;

    let updateAuthority = nft.updateAuthorityAddress?.toString();
    let mintAuthority = nft.mint.mintAuthorityAddress?.toString();
    let freezeAuthority = nft.mint.freezeAuthorityAddress?.toString();
    let decimals = nft.mint.decimals;

    const baseAndQuoteSwapped = tokenA.toBase58() === SOL_TOKEN;

    const lpInitializationLogEntryInfo =
      extractLPInitializationLogEntryInfoFromLogEntry(
        findLogEntry("init_pc_amount", tx?.meta?.logMessages ?? []) ?? ""
      );

    const initCoinAmount = lpInitializationLogEntryInfo.init_coin_amount;
    const initPcAmount = lpInitializationLogEntryInfo.init_pc_amount;
    const openTime = lpInitializationLogEntryInfo.open_time;

    let pnl = 0;
    if (baseAndQuoteSwapped) {
      pnl = initCoinAmount / 10 ** SOL_DECIMALS;
    } else {
      pnl = initPcAmount / 10 ** SOL_DECIMALS;
    }

    const displayData = [
      {
        tokenAddr: mintAddr,
        quoteAddr: mintAddrB,
        poolAddr: poolAddr,
        liquidity: `${pnl} SOL`,
        openTime: openTime,
        name: name,
        symbol: symbol,
        decimals: decimals,
        mintAuthority: mintAuthority,
        freezeAuthority: freezeAuthority,
      },
    ];

    console.log("New LP Found");
    console.table(displayData);
    console.log();

    // await fetchMarketInfo(connection, marketIdAccount);

    insertSolanaTokenAttribute(
      mintAddr,
      mintAddrB,
      name,
      symbol,
      decimals,
      poolAddr
    ).then(() => {
      logger.info("Inserted solana token attribute");
    });
  } catch {
    logger.error("Error fetching transaction:", txId);
    return;
  }
}

// ----------------------------------
async function insertSolanaTokenAttribute(
  token_address: string,
  quote_address: string,
  token_name: string,
  token_symbol: string,
  token_decimals: number,
  pair_address: string
) {
  const client = await g_pool.connect();
  try {
    g_dao.begin(client);

    let result = await g_dao.insertSolanaTokenAttribute(
      token_address,
      token_name,
      token_symbol,
      token_decimals,
      client
    );

    result = g_dao.insertSolanaTokenCount(
      pair_address,
      token_address,
      quote_address,
      client
    );

    //  commit
    g_dao.commit(client);
  } catch (error) {
    // 回滚
    g_dao.rollback(client);
    throw new Error(`Error adding solana token attribute: ${error}`);
  } finally {
    client.release();
  }
}
// ----------------------------------
function connectAndStart() {
  wssConn = new Connection(config.http_url, {
    wsEndpoint: config.wss_url,
  });

  startConnection(wssConn, RAYDIUM, INSTRUCTION_NAME)
    .then(() => logger.info("Connected and monitoring logs"))
    .catch(console.error);
}

connectAndStart();


